# Symlinking issues leading to file not found

Tags: php, apache, unix, laravel, symlink

In my home directory I have a laravel project folder:

```
/home
  /user
    /project
      /public     <--------.
        index.php          |
      /bootstrap           |
        autoload.php       |
      /config              |
        /public            |
/src                       |
  /http                    |
    /project (softlink to here)
```

In `project/public/index.php` I have this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

I soft-linked my apache public folder to the public folder in my user directory:

```
$ ln -s /home/user/project/public /srv/http/project
```

So I should be able to open `localhost/project`. But I get a 500 internal server error. Here is the relevant log from apache:

```
$ cat /var/log/httpd/error_log
[Tue Jun 02 2015] [:error] PHP Warning:  require(/home/user/project/config/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/project/config/public/index.php on line 21, referer: http://localhost/project/
[Tue Jun 02 2015] [:error] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/user/project/config/public/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='/home/user/project/vendor/phpunit/php-text-template:/home/user/project/vendor/phpunit/php-timer:.:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/project/config/public/index.php on line 21, referer: http://localhost/project/
```

The logs suggest that the server is looking for `/home/user/project/config/bootstrap/autoload.php`. Why though? I did not link to `/home/user/project/config/public`. I have no idea is this is an issue with apache, php, the link or the file system.

Comment: Do you have the [`FollowSymLinks`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) option set?

Comment: @hoss My `httpd.conf` contains `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`, so it should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
/home
  /user
    /project
      /public     <--------.
        index.php          |
      /bootstrap           |
        autoload.php       |
      /config              |
        /public            |
/src                       |
  /http                    |
    /project (softlink to here)
```

So with the symlink flattened your docroot looks like:

```
/src
  /http
    /project
        index.php
```

`../bootstrap` does not exist as far as your application is concerned.

Move your symlink up one level:

```
$ ln -s /home/user/project /srv/http/project
```

Comment: So after a break and a restart I went ahead and made the symlink you suggested and `localhost/project/public` works (It has another error, but that is unrelated). I then created a new link to the original location that works now. So I do not think that this is the answer that solved this problem. Should I mark this as answer as correct anyways?